# Getting data from axios in component

Tags: vue.js

I have this:

```
mounted() {
        axios
           .get("/news/all")
           .then((response) => (this.articles = response.data));
    }
```

The response is for instance:`[ { "article_id": 1, "post_time": "2023-12-24 08:15:09.110104", "article_content": "Test" } ]`

I have tried:

```
<template>
        <div class="content">
            <h1 class="center">Nyheter</h1>
            <div class="news-content">            
               {{ articles }} 
               <Blog :articles="{ articles }" />                                   
            </div>       
        </div>
    </template>
```

But it does not work. How do I write in the template?
If I write: `<Article :articles="[ { "article_id": 1, "post_time": "2023-12-24 08:15:09.110104", "article_content": "Test" } ]"` it works, but how do I write to use the get request data ?

Comment: did you try `<Blog :articles="articles" />  `

Comment: I did now and it worked. Thank you very much, Boussadjra Brahim. :)